# Function in C to add <SPACE> after every non space character in a string

Tags: c

This is what I'm trying to make work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * xspace(char *s)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = strlen (s);
    char final_string[n];

    for (i; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        final_string[j] = s[i];

        if(s[i] != ' ')
        {
            final_string[j + 1] = ' ';

        }

        j++;
    }

    final_string[j] = '\0';

    return final_string;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100], final_string[200];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    xspace(str);

    printf("\n%s\n", final_string);

}
```

All I get when trying to run this are [random symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFNkL.png) and I can't identify what's causing it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `final_string` is not large enough: it has, in the worst case, twice as many characters as `s`. Also, you return `final_string` but discard the returned value. The `final_string` in main() is not the same as the `final_string` in xspace().

Comment: If you did use the return value it would be a dangling pointer since it's pointing to a local variable that has been destroyed.

Comment: I figured `final_string` only needed to be twice as big as `s`.  Removing it from the `char` line on main seems to solve the problem tho, thank you guys!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "space" character?  Just the one literal space char `' '`, or any character where `isspace()` returns true?

Comment: Just the one literal space char `' '`. @AndrewHenle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* xspace(char* s)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    const int n = strlen(s);

    // maximum size of this string can be 2*n
    char* final_string= malloc(2 * n);

    // add extra spaces 
    for (i; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        final_string[j] = s[i];

        if (s[i] != ' ')
        {
            final_string[++j] = ' ';
        }

        j++;
    }
    final_string[j] = '\0';

    return final_string;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    // get final string
    char* final_string = xspace(str);

    // print final string
    printf("\n%s\n", final_string);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is working much better, however, the `if (s[i] != ' ')` statement doesn't seem to be applying, as it is adding spaces after every character, including `' '`.

Comment: I don't think so it's adding spaces after ` `. I have tested it, it's working fine.

Comment: Exactly, the idea was to **not** add spaces after `' '`, only after other characters. But this is more than helpful already, I'll try to figure it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here (well, there are more problems, but the one you talk about garbage characters appearing)

```
int main()
{
    char str[100], final_string[200];
```

the variable `final_string` is declared here, with no initialization.

```
    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    xspace(str);
```

it is not used anywhere, so you don't initialize it to anything that is usable.

```
    printf("\n%s\n", final_string);
```

and finally you print it here, just demonstrating that uninitialized local variables store rubbish.

```
}
```

Apart of that, to make your `xspaces` function to work, I would pass it two more arguments at least, to indicate the string you want to fill out with the copied string, and the size of that buffer, so w will not buffer overrun it when writing it.

My version of it is shorter than yours, here it is:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* macro used in formatting error messages (see ERR macro below) */
#define F(_fmt) "%s:%d:%s:"_fmt,__FILE__,__LINE__,__func__

/* pretty printing error function.  It exits if _code != 0 with
 * that error code */
#define ERR(_code, _fmt, ...) do {                  \
            fprintf(stderr, F(_fmt),##__VA_ARGS__); \
            if (_code) exit(_code);                 \
        } while(0)

/* macro to check, emit an error message and exit if not enough
 * capacity to add N more characters to buffer */
#define CHK_CAP(N) do{                              \
            if (cap < (N)) {                        \
                ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,                   \
                        "not enough space in bu"    \
                        "ffer(%zd) to store"        \
                        " result\n", initial_cap);  \
            }                                       \
        }while(0)

char *                      /* return the converted string */
xspaces(char* src,          /* source string */
        char *initial_buff, /* buffer to fill with the return string */
        size_t initial_cap) /* buffer capacity */
{
    char *tgt = initial_buff;
    size_t cap = initial_cap;
    for (; *src; src++) {
        bool is_space = isspace(*src);
        CHK_CAP(is_space ? 2 : 3); /* this counts for the final \0 */
        *tgt++ = *src; /* output the char */
        if (!is_space) *tgt++ = ' '; /* the space */
    }
    /* finish the string */
    CHK_CAP(1);
    *tgt++ = '\0';
    return initial_buff;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100], str_out[200];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    // print final string
    printf("\n%s\n",
            xspaces(str, str_out, sizeof str_out));
    return 0;
}
```